# How to return to the previous function by setting a flag using promises

Tags: ajax, promise, extjs5, deferred, extjs6-classic

I am making multiple ajax calls using promises how do I return to the previous function by setting a flag. I have a save function in which I am calling a method `if(!x()){return;}` I want to return some flag out of the x function I used promises for making the ajax calls as I need to wait for multiple ajax request responses and depending on it I have to submit the form. Please check the fiddle[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2c3i)

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to return a value from an asynchronous function to the code that called it. That's impossible. (the fiddle is useless)

Comment: The test `if (!this.refValid()) { ... }` proves @KevinB to be right. `refValid()` does a bunch of asynchronous stuff and should return a promise (which it can do with no need for a Deferred).
This question is a rather extensive example of something that is answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is a nightmare unless you are familiar with Promises.

As far as I can tell, you want something like this :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyModel1FormViewController', {
    'extend': 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    'alias': 'controller.mymodel1form',
    'save': function (button, e, eOpts, processed) {
        var me = this;
        // enable/disable "submit" button based on Promise-wrapped result from refValid()
        return this.refValid().then(function(bool) {
            // success handler
            me.onSubmit(button, e, eOpts, bool);
            Ext.Msg.alert('save: success');
        }, function (e) {
            // error handler
            // me.onSubmit(button, e, eOpts, ???); true|false or maybe just leave the button in its current state?
            Ext.Msg.alert('save: errors');
            // throw e; // rethrow the error to inform save()'s caller.
        });
    },
    'refValid': function (button, e, eOpts) {
        var detailStore = this.getView().up('panel').lookupReference('list').getStore(),
            jde = this.getView().up('panel').lookupReference('headerform').lookupReference('jdeno').getValue();
        var promises = detailStore.data.items.map(function (r) { // ???
            return r.get('refno') || null;
        }).filter(function (x) {
            return !!x; // filter out any nulls
        }).map(function (customerInvoiceDebitNo) {
            return Ext.Ajax.request({
                'url': 'data1.json',
                'timeout': 120000,
                'method': 'GET',
                'params': {
                    'addressNumber': jde,
                    'documentNumber': customerInvoiceDebitNo
                },
                'customerInvoiceDebitNo': customerInvoiceDebitNo
            }).then(function (response) {
                if (Ext.decode(response.responseText).data.length === 0) {
                    return false; // null
                } else {
                    Ext.Array.remove(customerInvoiceDebitNo); // maybe not necessary?
                    return true; // not null
                }
            });
        });
        return Ext.Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) { // results is array of booleans
            // Scan the results to check whether or not all are `true`,
            // and return <boolean>.
            return results.reduce(function (prev, current) {
                return prev && current;
            }, true);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Roamer!  I tried putting your code in the fiddle but got some errors can you please take a look at this https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2c4e

Comment: Answer edited. It runs now all the way through to "Save: success". I don't how to test whether a "save" actually happens.